# How to limit memory cost when request big data files？

Tags: python-3.x, download, io, request, bigdata

I want to download file from my minio server：

```
response = client.get_object(bucket_name, object_name, version_id)
res_data: str = response.data.decode('utf8')
```

When I run `decode` method, all datas will be extracted to memory and if this file is too large(>4GB, i.e.), the python process will crash.

So how to limit memory cost when request big data files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when dealing with large files, it is important to load the files into chunks.

For example:

```
response = client.get_object(bucket_name, object_name, version_id
# Define a chunk size (for example 1MB)
chunk_size = 1024 * 1024
# Process the file in chunks
for chunk in response.stream(chunk_size):
    decoded_chunk = chunk.decode('utf8')
    file.write(chunk)
```